# Not sure how to save in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push to a `sub-collection` for a `MongoDB` and I am not sure how to go about it.

So, my **post** collection structure:

```
{
    "_id": "58a3189b67476b420e465f8b",
    "postID": "123456",
    "comments": [
        {
            "subComments": [],
            "comment": "This is a test",
            "commentID": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So, what I want to do is find the above document using `findOneAndUpdate` and then select this particular `comment` (**commentID == 1**), and then push into the `subComments` of it.

I can see how you can `findOneAndUpdate` by it's `postID` and add `comments` by pushing in `Mongoose` but how do I find the `post`, and then the `comment` by it's `commentID` and then push into it's `subComment`?

Thanks in advance guys! Very stuck on this last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to other `find` queries.

You can try this:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({
    "postID" : givenPostID,
    "comments.commentID" : givenCommentID
},{ 
    $push : {
        "comment.$.subComments" : givenSubComment
    }
},function(err,result){...});
```

`comments.commentID: givenCommentID` will find the `comment` element with `commentID == givenCommentID`.

`comment.$.subComments` will `push` `givenSubComment` to the `subComments` array of the `matched` element of the `comments` array (matched based on commentID).

For more information Please read [MongoDB $(update) operator documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Comment: If something like this works, life will be great. However, the below line doesn't seem to work: {$push:{ comments.$.subComments : req.body.comment}} - I can't seem to find any documentation on this type of "push" either as my problem seems to be a syntax error. My editor is warning me of this already. Any ideas mate? Thanks

Comment: this works mate, let me update the answer with a link. also, i have edited the answer a bit, please try that, i am sure it will work. It turns out i had missed `"` in the update query.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet as I am not near my home PC. I will in the evening and update this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It didn't work. I am getting the below error: 

{ [MongoError: '$push' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {<field>: ...}}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: '\'$push\' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {<field>: ...}}',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: '\'$push\' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {<field>: ...}}',
  code: 9 }

Any ideas mate? Very lost here....

Comment: Also, I must specify that I am using Mongoose. Maybe the syntax is different. I will try and see if I can dig that out as well.

Comment: i have given syntax for mongoose only, I have tried this query lots of times. You just try and see if it works. I m positive that it will work

Comment: You are right - it works!!! It was a typo on my end. Thanks a million man. You saved my life!